# Where is WPF Performance Suite in Visual Studio 2015 / Windows 10?

Tags: wpf, performance, winapi, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Previously WPF Performance Suite was part of Windows SDK.

I have Windows 10 and VS 2015 Update 3.

This page https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk says: Windows 10 SDK is available with VS Update 3.

I can see Windows Performance tools (WPA) but not WPF Performance Suite.

Here is what I have in my apps on Windows..

[image]

Comment: [Where to Download WPF Performance Suite?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kirillosenkov/2016/04/05/where-to-download-wpf-performance-suite-perforator-visual-profiler/)

Comment: it worked thank you :) make it an answer please.